# Displaying data from XML via Linq on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a problem with XML (like in the title). I have XML sheet:

```
<Wallet>
    <Record>
        <Data>12.06.2017</Data>
        <Amount>1999</Amount>
        <Desc>Example desc</Desc>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <Data>12.08.2017</Data>
        <Amount>580</Amount>
        <Desc>Example desc 2</Desc>
    </Record>
</Wallet>
```

I tried to serialize that something like that:

```
public class Record
{
    [XmlElement("Data")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Amount")]
    public int Amount { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Desc")]
    public string Desc { get; set; }
}
```

And make it a list. But then I had a problem with displaying this into TextBox. Important information: I'm working now on Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1.

Could you help me please? I will be thankful :)

Best greetings!

Comment: can you please show the relevant code, what you tried for displaying it?

Comment: If you are going into a control you probably need an Observable List, not a standard list.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad See below for code :)

Answer (score 0):

I was displaying it in that way (example is in normal console application and not with list):

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load(@"path");

        IEnumerable<XElement> records = xelement.Elements();
        foreach (var record in records.Reverse())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}",  record.Element("Data").Value,
                record.Element("Amount").Value,
                record.Element("Desc").Value);
        }
```

This is very simple, but it works. I don't know how to display this in textbox or something on Windows Phone.